# How do i automate setting the properties of headers in a CSV file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

My program is hardcoded to know the headers of a CSV file.

```
 public class PeopleDataClass // here we say each value is going to be a property in my class
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    }
```

And using this i can then set how i want to change it into JSON/ XML in another function for example:

```
 public static void turnCsvIntoXml() // XML Data
    {
        var csvData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:example\PeopleData.csv"); 
        XElement xml = new XElement("PeopleFromPersonData",
        from str in csvData
        let columns = str.Split(',')
        select new XElement("People",
            new XElement("Name", columns[0]),
            new XElement("AddressLine1", columns[1]),
            new XElement("AddressLine2", columns[2]))

        );
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
```

My question is how do i set those properties automatically, so that a user can input their own file location (i have this set up already to take the users input as a variable and use that instead).

So if the user inputs a file of a CSV which has the headers 'Country, Year, Age, Mothers Name'.
How do i make that process of setting the the headers as properties and then using the automatically set properties to convert the data into JSON/XML

Comment: You need [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: @trailmax : Why use a library that isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
    public class PeopleDataClass // here we say each value is going to be a property in my class
    {
        public static List<string> headers { get; set; }
        public List<string> row { get; set; }

    }
```